# Custom standard input for python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I'm running an SSH process like this:

```
sshproc = subprocess.Popen([command], shell=True)
exit = os.waitpid(sshproc.pid, 0)[1]
```

This works and opens an interactive terminal.  Based on the documentation for `subprocess`, `sshproc` is using the script's `sys.stdin`.

**The question is:** how can I print to stderr or a file what input is being received to this child process?  I am creating a logging API, and currently lose the ability to record what commands are run over this SSH session.

I don't need the answer, just a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks everyone!

**EDIT:** It is important that I start the process as shown above so that I can have a interactive SSH session with my user.  E.g. I cannot use `communicate()` as far as I know.

Answer (score 8):

```
sshproc = subprocess.Popen([command],
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )

stdout_value, stderr_value = sshproc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')
print repr(stdout_value)
print repr(stderr_value)
```

Ah since you said nudge in right direction, I thought I should point you to good readups:

- http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/
- [capture stderr from python subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914320/capture-stderr-from-python-subprocess-popencommand-stderrsubprocess-pipe-std)

-

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when using `communicate` my users lose the ability to use the SSH terminal interactively.

Answer (score 0):

correct link to @pyfunc's answer, http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/
Very informative source, subprocess, allows calling any number of other processes or bash commands, with all piping customizations.