# Python Script execute commands in Terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I read this somewhere a while ago but cant seem to find it. I am trying to find a command that  will execute commands in the terminal and then output the result.

For example: the script will be:

```
command 'ls -l'
```

It will out the result of running that command in the terminal

Comment: I guess by "terminal" you mean "as in the command line", see https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal

Answer (score 274, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

A simple way is using the os module:

```
import os
os.system("ls -l")
```

More complex things can be achieved with the subprocess module:
for example:

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen(["ping","-W","2","-c", "1", "192.168.1.70"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: I don't want to downvote you but. You should use subprocess for everything. It's way safer. subprocess.call() will get you a nice interface in order to replace the simple call form.

Comment: Thanks for that answer mate. Will be using python for my first application on Ubuntu desktop, this will really help me.

Comment: How can I get the complete response of a command, `os.system("nslookup gmail.com")` only returns the last line `0`, but I want to get the full response.

Comment: @JorgeVargas Can you help me understand why subprocess should be used for everything? Why is it safer?

Comment: I've done this with more complex subprocess and threaded management before, I wasn't aware it was great for simple one-off's also, thanks.

Answer (score 63):

I prefer usage of subprocess module:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Reason is that if you want to pass some variable in the script this gives very easy way for example take the following part of the code

```
abc = a.c
call(["vim", abc])
```

Comment: Worked well for me opening up a picture with extra parameters `call(["eog", "1breeproposal.png", "-f"])`

Answer (score 10):

```
import os
os.system("echo 'hello world'")
```

This should work. I do not know how to print the output into the python Shell.

Answer (score 8):

- [Custom standard input for python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729366/custom-standard-input-for-python-subprocess)

In fact any question on subprocess will be a good read

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess

Answer (score 8):

for python3 use subprocess

```py
import subprocess
s = subprocess.getstatusoutput(f'ps -ef | grep python3')
print(s)
```

You can also check for errors:

```py
import subprocess
s = subprocess.getstatusoutput('ls')
if s[0] == 0:
    print(s[1])
else:
    print('Custom Error {}'.format(s[1]))


# >>> Applications
# >>> Desktop
# >>> Documents
# >>> Downloads
# >>> Library
# >>> Movies
# >>> Music
# >>> Pictures
```

```py
import subprocess
s = subprocess.getstatusoutput('lr')
if s[0] == 0:
    print(s[1])
else:
    print('Custom Error: {}'.format(s[1]))

# >>> Custom Error: /bin/sh: lr: command not found
```

Answer (score 5):

You should also look into `commands.getstatusoutput`

This returns a tuple of length 2..
The first is the return integer (0 - when the commands is successful)
second is the whole output as will be shown in the terminal.

For ls

```
import commands
s = commands.getstatusoutput('ls')
print s
>> (0, 'file_1\nfile_2\nfile_3')
s[1].split("\n")
>> ['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3']
```

Answer (score 3):

In python3 the standard way is to use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

```
res = subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], capture_output=True)
print(res.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

The *os.popen()* is pretty simply to use, but it has been deprecated since Python 2.6.
You should use the *subprocess* module instead.

Read here: [reading a os.popen(command) into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339469/reading-a-os-popencommand-into-a-string/16266645#16266645)

Answer (score 1):

## Jupyter

In a jupyter notebook you can use the magic function `!`

```
!echo "execute a command"
files = !ls -a /data/dir/ #get the output into a variable
```

## ipython

To execute this as a `.py` script you would need to use `ipython`

```
files = get_ipython().getoutput('ls -a /data/dir/')
```

execute script

```
$ ipython my_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You could import the 'os' module and use it like this :

```
import os
os.system('#DesiredAction')
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Running**: subprocess.run
- **Output**: subprocess.PIPE
- **Error**: raise RuntimeError

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess


def runCommand (command):
    output=subprocess.run(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    if output.returncode != 0:
        raise RuntimeError(
            output.stderr.decode("utf-8"))

    return output


output = runCommand ([command, arguments])
print (output.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```