# Open an application with a script file loaded with '/s' in subprocess

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

To open an application in Windows named DriveMaster, I am using subprocess.Popen:

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\\v970\\DriveMaster.exe'])
```

Now, if I need to open DriveMaster with a script file loaded, what should I do? From windows command prompt or a windows batch file I run:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster.exe" /s:c:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\Scripts\ATA\SATA_TestBatch.srt
```

Now I need to open DriveMaster with the script file SATA_TestBatch.srt file. Please note there is '/s:' included in the command to load the script file.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730964/python-script-execute-commands-in-terminal

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you can try is to run the command as is:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster.exe" /s:c:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\Scripts\ATA\SATA_TestBatch.srt')
```

Comment: But this involves, and indeed requires, the shell, which can easily be avoided here.

Comment: @tripleee: **wrong**. Popen does *not* use the shell by default.

Comment: Note the use of double quotes around the executable's path. Without them `CreateProcess` scans `lpCommandLine` for whitespace from left to right to find the executable's path. For example, without quotes it tries `C:\Program`, `C:\Program Files (x86)`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO`, and finally `C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster.exe`. If any of the latter doesn't exist it also tries appending a `.EXE` extension before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\\v970\\DriveMaster.exe', r'/s:c:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\Scripts\ATA\SATA_TestBatch.srt'])
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence.

Comment: it causes `SyntaxError`. Use raw-string literals for Windows paths: `r'...\U..'`

Comment: An error is raised you're right. It's actually a FileNotFoundError. My bad, I rarely use Windows :) . Answer edited, thank you Sebastian. Tested using Python3.4 for Windows : `subprocess.Popen(['C:\test.bat', '--my-test-arg']` . Test.bat contains `echo %1%`, and it prints `--my-test-arg`

Comment: No. If the path has `'\U'` in it then SyntaxError is raised