# How to run a terminal command inside a python script?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, command

On a mac preferably, what are the modules you need to import or just what to write to run something simple like: a python script to open a terminal and use the screencapture command on mac terminal to capture your screen image every minute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Script execute commands in Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730964/python-script-execute-commands-in-terminal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with:

```
import os
os.system('...your command...')
```