# How to integrate a terminal into a text editor created with python-tk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I took help from this website https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/make-notepad-using-tkinter/ and used the code to create a full-fledged text editor which was like the windows Notepad.
Now, I want to integrate a terminal into it so that it can run the programs there itself.

Comment: The `-container` option to a frame sets it up to contain another window (that's Tk, not python tkinter).    Reparenting or embedding another window is different on every system.  You'll have to specify which OS you are using.

Comment: Windows 10 please

Comment: There is this information:  https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Reparenting+native+applications+on+Windows , but you'll need to work out how to translate the information there into tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this:

[os.system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730964/python-script-execute-commands-in-terminal)

make sure to check the path of the file that you want to run

Comment: Elaborate. I can't understand.

Comment: we use os.system('terminal command') so for executing a file
we use os.system('python file_path') make sure file_path 
 is accurate (use file dialog widget for that)